# WebDriverException in Selenium using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am using python 3 on windows, using the Selenium package for web crawling using Chrome. I am running on a new computer, doing everything the same, but get the following error immediately in the first run. I never saw this exception. Anyone is familiar with it and can shed some light? Thanks.

```
    WebDriverException: session not created exception
    from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"9668.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
      (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

The exception happens immediately at the beginning at the driver call:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

UPDATE:
after upgrading to chromeDriver2.4, there is a different error which I never saw before:

WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Any ideas?? Thanks...

Comment: Could you share problematic code and browser name as well??

Comment: Thank you @SaurabhGaur. Added it.

Comment: Did you provide executable chromedriver path??

Comment: There is no need, as the chromedriver.exe is in the working directory... I don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to update to the latest driver. I had the same problem--was using using 2.22 and updated to 2.24. Solved the issue.

Forlatest driver see here:
(Click latest release)
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks @DanielGlasgow. I did that, but now am getting a different error in the `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` line: 

        WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)